# How to automate to get image size and url in a webpage/website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Can we automate to get individual image size(Kb) in a webpage/website using selenium. there is any tool/process is available to automate this process. I want to automate to get all images URL having more than 50kb in a webpage/website. Please give your suggestions on this.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: using developer tools==>Network

Comment: You can fetch the urls using selenium and then send a request to each of the urls using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library and fetch the size of the image.

Comment: Can you please send me the hot code for this, that would be a great help for me...

Answer (score 0):

To get an image size on the webpage, you could ask to server. i.e; use URLConnection class to represent a communication link between application and that URL.

```
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(we.getAttribute("src")).openConnection();
size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

This should work well and check the condition which has more than 50kB and get those urls. Hope this code must helps you.