# how to get Img size in Network tab of chrome developer tool

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]Hi Team i want to get the following data's in Network tab of Chrome developer tool

1. Get the list of Img in Network Tab
2. Get the Size of all the Img one by one

I could able to get the status code with the following code. But i could not able to get the Img concept

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.connect();
        return huc.getResponseCode();
    }
```

Kindly help me to get the list of Img and their sizes

Comment: team kindly help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the content length of the image file . To get an image size on the webpage, you could ask to server. i.e; use `URLConnection` class to represent a communication link between application and that URL.

```
 List<WebElement> listofimages = driver.findElements(By.tagName('img'));
  for(WebElement d : listofimages){

 URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(d.getAttribute("src")).openConnection();
 size = urlConnection.getContentLength();}
 //get the locator to image here
 WebElement we = driver.findElement(Locator_to_image_here);

 URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(we.getAttribute("src")).openConnection();
 size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  
}
```

Edit 1: This answer has been picked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886582/how-to-automate-to-get-image-size-and-url-in-a-webpage-website) SO post. Credits to the original poster.

Edit 2 : For getting all the images, you need to get all the elements by tagname( please check how this locator is used in Java- I'm not entirely sure) 'img' since all the images would be having this tag. Have these elements in a list and then iterate over that list and get the connection per element in list and then get the size.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But i need to get the list of Image Locator dynamically from Network Tab first and then get the size of it.

Comment: Kindly tell me how get the lis of Img in Network Tab first. this is my scenario

Comment: Edited the answer.